# How to Parse multiple classes from groovy file

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to parse all all the classes in a groovy script?
To Parse ONE class right now:

```
java.lang.Class clazz = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(new File("MainApp.groovy"))
```

MainApp.groovy:

```
class MainApp {
   def doIt() {}
}

class OtherMainApp {
  def doTheRest() {}
}
```

This will return only MainApp.

I would like something like this:

```
java.lang.Class[] clazz = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(new File("MainApp.groovy"))
```

where clazz contains will contain both MainApp class and OtherMainApp class

Basically I want to be able to extract all the declared classes in a script.

Because of the nature of the app that I'm building groovyc command won't help

Thanks,

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3793

You could do it yourself though: you could parse the class yourself (just count the `{}` pairs), dump it out to a new file, and away you go. Ugly? yes. Painful? Very. Possible? Maybe. Better solution? Not until Groovy fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 12 years since this question was asked and answered, but it arrived at the top of my Google results when I was trying to figure out how to do the same thing.

This ended up working for me:

```
def loader = new GroovyClassLoader()
loader.parseClass(new File("Company.groovy"))
Class Location = loader.loadClass("tk.vallerance.spacecompanies.models.Location")
Class Event = loader.loadClass("tk.vallerance.spacecompanies.models.Event")
Class Company = loader.loadClass("tk.vallerance.spacecompanies.models.Company")

println Location
println Event
println Company
```